# jQuery validation plugin error: TypeError: validator is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here is html code for the form:

```
<form method="post" id="login" action="/login">
 <div class="login-element">
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</div>
<div class="login-element">
    <label for="password">Passwort</label>
    <input type="password"  name="password">
</div>
<div class="login-element">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the code that I used for validation:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#login").validate({
       debug: true,
       rules: {
            email: {
              required: true,
              email: true
            },
            password: {
              required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter a email adress",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            password:"Please enter password"
        }
    });
    });
```

In the console following error is logged:

```
TypeError: validator is undefined
...or.settings[eventType] && validator.settings[eventType].call(validator, this[0],...
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the plugin itself.

Comment: I thought that could be the issue. But in head I have following:
`code`
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/login-validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: That doesn't mean anything if they're not all located at those URL's without giving you any 404 errors.

Comment: Are you using compatible versions of jQuery and Validate?

Comment: Once I realized that validate.js was imported to the page duplicated (from a master page layout and another one from subviews). So that client-side validation has not been working. After removing duplicated imports, it worked perfect.

Answer (score 23):

This error happened because I had another html element with same id.
After removing that id code worked fine.

Comment: Additional note: I was having a similar error, the solution, in my case was to remove an extra validation update which referred to an ID which no longer existed...

Comment: I forgot to add class to the variable (which contained HTML to append) that I was targeting for validation after dynamically adding elements. i was getting `TypeError: j is undefined`. Though error was different(but similar, which led me to this post) the problem was same as described here. Thanks.

Comment: my error was caused because i have forgot to close a tag within my form. i had `<ul>` instead `</ul>` humph!

Answer (score 14):

For anyone still looking for an answer and the answers above dont work..

I spent the last 3 hours trying all the solution and none of them worked.

I finally realized a very stupid mistake , I had initialized Jquery twice in my application

once in the head where i had included 3 scripts

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

and once again at the end of the page where i only had the line.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

This was resetting the validator function of $ and causing everything to break.

Some things to check for cases where validations are not firing.

1. Is the script in correct order ? jquery followed by validate followed by unobstrusive.
2. Is the $.validator function defined ? Check quickly in the console of the browser
3. Is the form to be validated being created dynamically ? If so , you may need to re initialize the validator plugin on the form , the best way i have found of doing this are mentioned below , choose the one which fits well for you.

   ```
   $.validator.unobstrusive.parse('#myForm')
   ```

or

```
 $('#myForm').validate() // this just makes the validator plugin consider the form for unobstrusive validation
```

or

```
$('#myForm').valid() // this will trigger unobstrusive validation on the form.
```

4. If you have complicated ajax loads for many forms , make sure that the scripts are not included again and again in each ajax page , also make sure that elements on the main page still have unique names.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what was going on in my case. I had jQuery initialized at the header and then in one of the ajax component. As a result the jQuery.validator  was null. Once I removed the duplicate initialization from the AJAX component, it worked! Thank you.

Comment: For me I had `jquery.validate-vsdoc.js` referenced as well. I guess this causes it to throw the error.

Answer (score 11):

You need to include the validation script in the head of your document.

Like this:

```
<script src="/js/libs/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, please check in the rendered HTML that your form ID is correct.

I use this code for calling validate on my sites

```
        //Validate Form
        var ids = [];
        $("form").each(function () {
            ids.push(this.id);
        });
        var formId = "#" + ids[0]
        $(formId).validate();
```

Comment: I am sure that I included jquery.validate.js because this error is thrown on line 316 from that file.

Comment: @AndrewWalters, there's nothing wrong with the OP's code as he's posted it.

Comment: Nope, but actually I solved problem. You pointed me in right direction - problem was id. I had another html element with same id.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue showed up for me. The reason for that error what that I was using the code:

```
if ($("#invalidFormId").valid()) {
....
}
```

And the `id` of the `form` element was not valid

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was because the validator was being called too early. I moved the code to a seperate function and called it using delay method of underscore.js. Worked like a charm.

```
_.delay(doValidations);

function doValidations() {
...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this is the first topic that Google shows for "validator is undefined" then I will describe my solved problem, maybe someone will find it helpfull.

I was using 'maxlength' attribute (nothing fancy) and I got this error. The reason was nested forms. One of the textarea was inside both forms. Can happen when you have modals (dialogs) with forms in main view.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem came that had two instanced versions of Jquery UI i JQuery. This made that Jquery normal code works fine but delete the intance of $.validator.

Answer (score 1):

I had `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in the parent view (_Layout.cshtml) and had also defined some other jquery Script tags in another view, they clashed.

Answer (score 1):

I had `form="form-name` attribute within my `<input>` element. Removing it immediately solves the error.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin comes in separate libraries, you need to include those in your html.

```
<script src="../jquery-validation/dist/jquery-validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened here. For me it was a typo in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //START of validate
$('#reply').validate({
    rules:{
        message:{
            required: true,
            },  
        },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var data = $("#reply").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax/scripts/msg_crt.php",
            data:data,
            success:function(data){
                alert("Loaded");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //END of validate
  });

$(document).on('click','#send', function(){
    if($('#replay').valid()){// <--- Here is my selector typo
        $("#replay").submit(); // <--- Here is my selector typo
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occurring for me when calling validator.destroy() - the error was occurring within the staticRules method of the plugin. The cause turned out to be the associated form element (element.form) was detached from the DOM. I resolved it by checking the element was in the DOM before calling destroy, using the following method:

```
document.contains(element)
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was calling `$.validator` *before* `$(document).ready`. Once I moved it to a function being called from `ready`, it worked. It will work after or during `ready` but not before.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting following error :

**Uncaught TypeError: d is undefined**

error was occurring becasue form id and model div id where same.
after changing id error was resolved.