# Add Validation Rules Dynamically to MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

All,

I need to add validation rules to dynamic form input text elements added by the user.

I am accomplishing this by cloning a chunk of HTML, providing unique ids and adding to the DOM

I researched the syntax for this, which I believe is correct yet I am getting the following JS error when I try to access the *.rules* method:

```
TypeError: $(...).rules is not a function
```

**Caused by this:**

```
$("input[type=text].validateRequired").each(function () {

     $(this).rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "Data is missing" }   

   });     
 });
```

When I examine `$(this)` in FireBug, I do not see a .rules method yet it exists in the validation scripts and all of the documentation shows that the method should be available globally. Not sure how to get it in scope.

Here are the code pieces in the View related to this problem:

**JS Includes**

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS Method that creates the dynamic form elements**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var uniqueId = 1;
        var ctr = 1;
        $(function() {
            $('.js-add-cosponsor-hyperlink').click(function() {

                var copy = $("#cosponsorsTemplate").clone(true).appendTo("#addCosponsorSection").hide().fadeIn('slow');
                var cosponsorDivId = 'cosponsors_' + uniqueId;
                var copyText = copy.html();

                copyText = copyText.replace(/Guitar1/g, 'Guitar' + ctr);
                copyText = copyText.replace('Guitar_1', 'Guitar_' + ctr);
                copy.html(copyText);
                $('#cosponsorsTemplate').attr('id', cosponsorDivId);



                var deleteLink = copy.find("a.icon.delete");
                deleteLink.on('click', function() {
                    copy.fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); }); //fade out the removal

                });


                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                $("input[type=text].validateRequired").each(function () {

                    var t = $(this);
                    $(this).rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "Data is missing" } });
                });

                uniqueId++;
                ctr++;
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

****The Form****

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
      [...]


       <!-- Template used to do the Clone: These need dynamic validation -->

       <div style="display:none">
         <div id="cosponsorsTemplate">
                <div class="formColumn1"><label>Guitar</label></div>
             <div class="formColumn2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitar1.Make, new { Placeholder = "Make", Class = "validateRequired" })
               <div class="messageBottom"> 
                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitar1.Make)
                </div>
             </div>
                <div class="formColumn3">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitar1.Model, new { Placeholder = "Model" , Class = "validateRequired"})
                    <div class="messageBottom"> 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitar1.Model)
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="formColumn4">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitar1.ProductionYear, new { Placeholder = "Production Year", Class = "validateRequired" })
                             <div class="messageBottom"> 
                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitar1.ProductionYear)
                             </div><a class="icon delete">Delete</a>
                          </div>

          </div>
    </div>    
    <!-- End Add Co-Sponsor Row Template -->
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning a chunk of HTML so every time you do a clone you need to parse the whole form
by using $.validator.unobtrusive.parse

Comment: cannot get to that either: TypeError: $.validator is undefined

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

Comment: it's look like you don't have included the right reference of Javascript Vaidate plugin. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407312/jquery-validation-plugin-error-typeerror-validator-is-undefined

Comment: the libraries are there as they do unobtrusively validate the non-dynamic elements just fine - this is really strange