# JQuery + TinyMCE = TypeError: validator is undefined

Tags: jquery, validation, tinymce, undefined

StackOverflow!  This is my first question here, so be gentle! ;)

I have searched SO from top to bottom but could not find a solution for "TypeError: validator is undefined" in my code below.

The only thing I found was this Q&A: [jQuery validation plugin error: TypeError: validator is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407312/jquery-validation-plugin-error-typeerror-validator-is-undefined)

It seems like everyone had a similar issue where the form ID's were not valid.  I checked all my ID's and they are right.

A few details about my site:

My code is stored in a .js file and is loaded on every page.  I load it on every page in an "include" file where all of my custom JavaScript code lives (this, of course EXCLUDES JQuery.js, bootstrap.js, etc.).  I do this so that I do not have to copy/paste the same code on hundreds of other pages, I just add the one "include" file.

On pages that do **NOT** utilize the TinyMCE form fields I always get the TypeError: validator is undefined" and all of my other JavaScript seems to freeze.  On pages where TinyMCE form fields are used, it works fine.

Please note that my code, shown below, is the result of other people's questions being answered here.  The "tinyMCE.triggerSave();" code, for example, has been a life saver when trying to validate TinyMCE fields.

So, does anyone see an issue below?  Will I be forced to load the code only on the pages that use TinyMCE?

```
    $(function() {
    var validator = $("#alert_notification_form").submit(function() {
                // Force MCE to update textarea before proceeding
                tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        }).validate({
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error',
            focusInvalid: true,
            ignore: '',             
            rules: {
                impact: {
                    required: true
                },
                further_info: {
                    required: true
                }   
            },
            messages:{

                impact: {
                    required: 'Please state how we will be affected.'
                },
                further_info: {
                    required: 'Further Information is required.'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent(".input-group").size() > 0) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent(".input-group"));
                } else if (element.attr("data-error-container")) {
                    error.appendTo(element.attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.radio-list').size() > 0) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-list').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.radio-inline').size() > 0) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-list').size() > 0) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-list').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-inline').size() > 0) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            }
    });
    validator.focusInvalid = function() {
            // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
            if (this.settings.focusInvalid) {
                try {
                    var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
                    if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
                        tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
                    } else {
                        toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
                }
            }
        }
    $(".reset").click(function() {
        validator.resetForm();
    });
});
```

UPDATE - 03/01/2015

I tried both suggestions below and I may be missing something else.  I found the "validator.focusinvalid" function in my code below came from the GIT repository here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/tinymce4/index.html

Could there be an issue with that validator function?  I tried removing the "tinyMCE.triggerSave();" completely and still get the TypeError: validator is undefined.

What am I missing? :(

For reference, I added the code where I initialize TinyMCE.

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
menubar: false,
plugins: "link, paste, lists, wordcount",
toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | paste",
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('change', function(e) {
        tinymce.triggerSave();
        $("#" + editor.id).valid();
    });
} });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load this script on all pages but you need a way to detect whether TinyMCE is active. You can do it by calling the following function and if true, execute `tinyMCE.triggerSave();`

```
function isTinyMCEActive()
{
    is_tinyMCE_active = false;
    if (typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined")
    {
        if (tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false)
        {
            is_tinyMCE_active = true;
        }
    }

    return is_tinyMCE_active;
}
```

This if for detecting whether TinyMCE is active.

Now, as for the "TypeError: validator is undefined" error, the problem might be caused by the way you're chaining the call to submit() and validate(). Here's an updated version of your code, with a call to the beforeSubmit() method to save the editors' values to their textareas. This way, you're targeting the form and then call the validate() method on submit (after textareas have been updated).

```
$(function() {
var validator = $("#alert_notification_form").validate({
       beforeSubmit:function() {
            // Force MCE to update textarea before proceeding
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            return true;
       },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error',
        focusInvalid: true,
        ignore: '',             
        rules: {
            impact: {
                required: true
            },
            further_info: {
                required: true
            }   
        },
        messages:{

            impact: {
                required: 'Please state how we will be affected.'
            },
            further_info: {
                required: 'Further Information is required.'
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent(".input-group").size() > 0) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent(".input-group"));
            } else if (element.attr("data-error-container")) {
                error.appendTo(element.attr("data-error-container"));
            } else if (element.parents('.radio-list').size() > 0) {
                error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-list').attr("data-error-container"));
            } else if (element.parents('.radio-inline').size() > 0) {
                error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
            } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-list').size() > 0) {
                error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-list').attr("data-error-container"));
            } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-inline').size() > 0) {
                error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function (label) {
            label
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
});
validator.focusInvalid = function() {
        // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
        if (this.settings.focusInvalid) {
            try {
                var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
                if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
                    tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
                } else {
                    toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
            }
        }
    }
$(".reset").click(function() {
    validator.resetForm();
});
});
```

Comment: Going to try this solution and the one posted next from Charlietfl below.  Will let you know how they work!

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to check for existence of an element or class of elements before initializing code that is only applicable to that type of element but might otherwise cause issues if code is run.

```
$(function(){
    if($('.someSpecialClass').length){
       /* code that applies only when selector exists */    
    }
});
```

Or if you have various options for a plugin depending on a class existing or not

```
var pluginOpts={
   foo:'some value'
}

if($('.someSpecialClass').length){
      $.extend(pluginOpts , {bar: 'another value'});   
}

$(selector).somePlugin(pluginOpts);
```